# Integer.toString() add "\u0000" characters, and if statement fails...

Tags: java, android, string, integer

OK, my first question in stackOverflow.

This is something that I left me completely baffled.

Java (I use android Studio), I write the following code:

```
    Integer aNumber = 200;
    String aNumberInString;
    aNumberInString = Integer.toString(aNumber);
    Boolean result;
    if(aNumberInString == "200"){
        result = true;
    } else {
        result = false;
    }

    Log.i("result:",result+"");
```

OK, logic and what I expect is that the condition is true... But NO! it fails.

I was really shocked by this behavior, then investigate a little more, and run the code in debug mode step by step.

when I get to the condition, I inspect the value of "aNumberInString" and to my surprise, this is what I find:

[image: SampleCode1]

OK, so the first thing I think is: "Integer.toString ()" are doing something wrong.

Let's try another way: "String.valueOf ()"

Run in debug mode, and:
[image: SampleCode2]

THE SAME! and fails, of course.

Obviously fails because it compares different characters, and in Internet I found a way to fix it,

```
string.replace ("\\ u0000", "");
```

but my question is not how to fix it, is:

### Why is this happening?

### Is there a correct way to prevent this from happening?

From already thank you very much to all,
Regards, Nicolas

Comment: don't use `==` for string comparisons, use `equals()`

Comment: Just a small note: your interpretation of the debug display is wrong: `aNumberString` contains the chars '2', '0' and '0' from offset 8, and that is the fields `offset` (8) and `count` (3) show.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing a reference comparison. For comparing Strings, you need to call `equals`. By doing `==` with an Object, you are asking Java to make sure they are the same object, not if they have the same value.

Change:

```
if(aNumberInString == "200"){
```

To this:

```
if(aNumberInString.equals("200") {
```

Or better yet, to reduce the chance of a `NullPointerExcpetion`:

```
if("200".equals(aNumberInString))
```

Comment: Thank you very much, i did not know the String.equal, now YES! ty bye :)